# Ctrl -c does not kill the for loop in bash script

Tags: bash

This is designed to skip any file from today or yesterday and to zip anything from this month or the previous month. So far it works fine, except that once the "gzip -9 $journal" executes, when you press "Ctrl -c" to kill the program, it loops to the next file and executes a "gzip -9 $journal". I have to hit the "Crtl -c" for as many times as there is a file in the directory. How can I structure the script to die when I hit "Ctrl -c".

```
#!/bin/bash

volume="/home/casper/vol14/"
dirLimit="casper_limit/"
dirConsu="casper_consumption/"
nowMonth=$(/bin/date +'%b' -d 'now')
preMonth=$(/bin/date +'%b' -d 'last month')
tradeDay=$(/bin/date -I)
previDay=$(/bin/date -I -d 'yesterday')
limtfile="MH_CASPER_LIMIT_01*.journal"


cd /home/casper/vol14/casper_limit/

for journal in $limtfile
do
filemodtime=$(/bin/date -I -r  $journal)
    if [[ "$filemodtime" == "$tradeDay" || "$filemodtime" == "$previDay" ]] ; then
    :
    else
        filemodMonth=$(/bin/date +'%b' -r $journal)
        if [[ "$filemodMonth" == "$nowMonth" || "$filemodMonth" == "$preMonth" ]] ; then
            if [[ -f "${journal}.gz" ]] ; then
                echo "Skipping ${journal}.gz is already zipped"
            else
            echo "$journal is from $filemodMonth and is being zipped"
            gzip -9 $journal
            fi
        fi

fi

done
```

Comment: how do you invoke the script? to my knowledge, if you invoke a script by calling it, like `./your_script.sh`, then `CTL+C` should kill the whole process; the problem is if you execute it by sourcing it, then `CTL+C` will only kill the current process, which is not the for loop.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr - I use ./myScript. I think that the "-9" in the gzip does something.

Comment: This similar question on ServerFault is likely of interest - https://serverfault.com/questions/105386/bash-loop-how-to-stop-the-loop-when-i-press-control-c-inside-a-command

Comment: unlikely. is that everything? do you trap any signal at all?

Comment: @zzevannn not quite the same event here. in the case of invocation as a script, SIGINT should be sent to the bash process that executes the script, which will terminates the process if not trapped. i don't understand how can in that situation sending SIGINT does not do that.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr - this is the whole script. It is like the innermost if statement just runs, and runs and runs.